# Logical issue in generating HTML code

Tags: python, html

I am trying generate HTML code using the code below(pastie link),expected output is shown below ,am getting an output where the CR value is getting added twice and also the http links are not right...can anyone help review the logic to see where I am going wrong

My code:-

```
    http://pastie.org/5391102
```

INput is below

```
http://pastie.org/5390316(if you copy/paste ,make sure they are tab seperated,otherwise you will get a key error)
```

Expected output:-

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">CR</th>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">FA</th>
 <th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">CL</th>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">Title</th>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452">409452</a></td>
 <td>WLAN</td>
<td>656885</td>
<td>Age out RSSI values from buffer </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href=http://data/409452>409452</a>,<a href=http://data/12345>12345</a></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>To Record HAL and SLM FW Event Logging</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My current output:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">CR</th>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">FA</th>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">CL</th>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">Title</th>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452">409452</a></td>
<td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452">409452</a></td>
 <td><a href=http://prism/CR/Title>Title</a></td>
 <td>wlan</td>
 <td>656885</td>
 <td>Age out rssi values from buffer</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452, 12345">409452, 12345</a></td>
<td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452, 12345">409452, 12345</a></td>
<td><a href=http://prism/CR/Title>Title</a></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
 <td>To Record HAL and SLM FW Event Logging</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your posted code has errors - you should post the fixed code that results in this output.

Comment: @thomas - i EDITED..here it is http://pastie.org/5391102

Comment: @martin - do you have any inputs on this pleasE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's that input I promised.

```
def CRlistToTable(CRlist):
    """ Create HTML table from CRlist data """
    CRstrings = ['<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">']

    # create table's header row from the first row of CRlist
    BGCOLOR = '#67B0F9' # column header cells background color
    cols = CRlist[0]  # column names given in first row
    CRstrings += ['  <tr>', '\n'.join(
                  '    <th bgcolor="{}" scope="col">{}</th>'.format(BGCOLOR, col_name)
                     for col_name in cols),
                  '  </tr>']

    # create a template for remaining non-header table rows
    TR_TEMPLATE = ['  <tr>',
                   '    <td>',
                   '      {}',  # for dynamically generated CR links
                   '    </td>', '\n'.join(
                  ['    <td>{}</td>'] * (len(cols)-1)), # one per remaining cols
                   '  </tr>']
    TR_TEMPLATE = '\n'.join(TR_TEMPLATE) # convert to a string

    # apply the row template created to remaining CRlist rows
    CR_LINK_TEMPLATE = '<a href=http://data/{0}>{0}</a>'
    for row in CRlist[1:]:
        if ',' not in row[0]:  # no comma-delimited items in first column?
            links = CR_LINK_TEMPLATE.format(row[0])
        else:
            CRs = row[0].replace(',', ' ').split()
            links = ',\n      '.join(CR_LINK_TEMPLATE.format(cr) for cr in CRs)
        row[0] = links
        CRstrings += [TR_TEMPLATE.format(*row)]

    CRstrings += ["</table>"]

    # return string list merged to a single long newline-delimited string
    return '\n'.join(CRstrings) + '\n'


with open('cr_fixes_tabbed.xml') as file:
    xmldata = file.read()  # read entire file into memory

FIXES_START_TAG, FIXES_END_TAG = '<Fixes>, </Fixes>'.replace(',', ' ').split()
# embedded fixes info starts right after the tag itself within the xml data
xmlFixesStart = xmldata.find(FIXES_START_TAG) + len(FIXES_START_TAG)
xmlFixesEnd = xmldata.find(FIXES_END_TAG)

# extract portion of file data within the FIXES tags into a list of lines
info = xmldata[xmlFixesStart:xmlFixesEnd].strip().splitlines()

# split non-blank lines of tab-delimited data into list of rows of column data
CRlist = [line.split('\t') for line in info if line] # skips blank lines

crInfo = CRlistToTable(CRlist) # convert list into html table
print crInfo
```

Output:

```html
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">CR</th>
    <th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">FA</th>
    <th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">CL</th>
    <th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href=http://data/409452>409452</a>
    </td>
    <td>WLAN</td>
    <td>656885</td>
    <td>Age out RSSI values from buffer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href=http://data/409452>409452</a>,
      <a href=http://data/12345>12345</a>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>To Record HAL and SLM FW Event Logging</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Browser view:

[image: html output viewed in browser]

Comment: Thanks,one problem i am seeing if the columns are more,for input like http://pastie.org/5395174 its giving an error like     CRstrings += [TR_TEMPLATE.format(*row)]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support..you have been excellent support,dont know what should i do to repay your support :-)

Comment: one question,what does {0} in CR_LINK_TEMPLATE = '<a href=http://data/{0}>{0}</a>' do?,i mean why {0},why not {1}?

Comment: The syntax for replacement fields in format strings optionally allows an element index between the brackets. Normally I don't bother, however it is useful in situations where there's a need to reference the same argument more than once in the string. i.e. `'{0}, {0}'.format(x)` vs `'{}, {}'.format(x, x)`